# Do I have Left Truncation or Right Censoring in my Survival/Event History Analysis?

Tags: survival, censoring, truncation

I am doing study that starts at a specific date, January 1st 2015, and ends on a specific date, December 31st 2015. My overarching research question revolves around modeling time between orders of product $n$ from store $i$. I decided the best way to set up the data is to let the time variable be the number of days between the last order of that product from that store.

For example, let's say store "1" orders product "10" on January 5th 2015, and then again on February 3rd 2015. The time variable for the second order would be 2015-02-03 minus 2015-01-05 (R Date formats) or $t=29$ days.

For all orders except the first order in the dataset of product $n$ from store $i$, the time variable is well defined. However, using the example above, time is not well defined for the order on January 5th 2015. Lets say store "1" also ordered product "10" on December 15th 2014. Then the time variable would be $t=21$ days. However, I cannot calculate this as it is outside of the scope of this study.

Essentially, the store was "at risk" of a new order before the study began.

Is this left truncation? [According to this resource from the stats department at Oxford](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~mlunn/lecturenotes1.pdf), it sounds like left truncation, "Left truncation occurs when the subjects have been at risk before entering the study...". However, it also sounds like it could be a weird case of right censoring as I know an estimated "lower bound" of time, the date the order occurred minus the beginning of the study. Are right censoring and left truncation linked?

Also, feel free to critique my data setup. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Left truncation requires careful consideration when using. For example, one issue that can arise is "immortal person time," which may create a selection bias. See Rothman, K. J. and Greenland, S. (1998). *Modern Epidemiology*, chapter Cohort Studies—Immortal Person Time. Lippincott-Raven, 2nd edition.

Comment: Another comment: your data structure will, perhaps, flow more easily if you have a concept defining the *Begining of Time* in the study sense.

Comment: @Alexis Can you expand a bit more about the "Beginning of Time" point?

Comment: If you do not have a well-formed theoretical construction of what the concept "enters the study" (in terms of time) *means*, you are likely to encounter difficulty formulating a measure of timing your study outcomes. For example, in event history analysis models (of varied methods) the Beginning of Time is defined to mean "The first period of time in which all observed units of analysis are at risk of experiencing the event/none have yet experienced the event." This paves the way to defining "length to observation" and (right) "censored" variables in such models.